# jQuery .each with Smarty variable in .tpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I have a page with the following html that appears numerous times with different phone numbers:

```
<div class="crm-content crm-contact_phone primary">
    <span>5555551212</span>
</div>
```

The phone number itself is displayed using a smarty variable in the form {$phone.i.phone}, where i is the array key in an array of phone numbers.

I want to be able to change the format of these phone numbers using js.

So for just one phone number, I was using the following in my smarty .tpl file:

```
{literal}
cj(function($){

  var phoneNumber = {/literal}{$phone.1.phone}{literal};

  var phoneNumberFormatted = '(' + phoneNumber.substr(0,3) + ') ' + phoneNumber.substr(3,3) + '-' + phoneNumber.substr(6);

  $(".crm-contact_phone span").text(phoneNumberFormatted);

});
{/literal}
```

So I figure, I need to do something along the lines of:

```
$('.crm-contact_phone span').each(function(i, obj) {
    var phoneNumber = '' + {/literal}{$phone.1.phone}{literal};   
}
```

but I have no idea how to replace the 1 inside the smarty variable, with the javascript index i.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.crm-contact_phone span').each(function(i, obj) {
      var phoneNumber = '' + {/literal}{$phone[i].phone}{literal}; 
}
```

Use the **bracket Notation** and replace it with **i** .

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach in the end, saving the entire smarty array to a js array using the following:

```
var phoneNumbers = {/literal}{$phone|@json_encode}{literal};
```

I could then just access the phone number by using pure js:

```
 var phoneNumber = phoneNumbers[i]['phone'];
```